# What is the correct way to use tracks_get() function in Python-VLC module?

Tags: python, vlc, python-vlc

I'm just trying to get to grips with the VLC Python module and while the documentation is really helpful and the samples over at https://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings/ have been great for the basic functions, I'm a little stuck with figuring out how to use the tracks_get() function within the Media class.

```
import vlc

def getCodec():

    file = "/video/video.mp4"

    VLCInstance = vlc.Instance()

    Media = VLCInstance.media_new(file)
    
    Media.parse()

    tracks = Media.tracks_get()

    for track in tracks:
            mediatype = track.type
            mediacodec = track.codec
           
            codec_desc = vlc.libvlc_media_get_codec_description(mediatype,mediacodec)
            print(str(codec_desc))
            
   
getCodec()
```

I have written the code above and this all works fine, but in the documentation [here](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.Media-class.html#tracks_get) it mentions that the result must be freed with tracks_release. I can't see any function with that name though. I have found a function called libvlc_media_tracks_release, but I cannot seem to supply that with the parameters that it wants. I have tried adding `vlc.libvlc_media_tracks_release(tracks, 2)` at the bottom of my code, but that comes up with the error `"ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_LP_MediaTrack instance instead of generator"`.

So my questions are, how do I call the tracks_release() function and thereby use the tracks_get() function correctly and why do I need free the result anyway? Will Python's garbage collection not deal with the object once it goes out of scope?

Comment: Update new version https://pypi.org/project/python-vlc/